# Clear PTT and Biltlocker

Tags: bitlocker

I have a Dell 3580 with Windows 11 (the factory was Win10).

I took out the SSD and inserted the m.2 disk and wanted to install a system on it. He didn't want to boot with a pen and started fumbling with UEFI.
I did so that I installed the system, but when I connected the previous SSD drive, it says that it is encrypted with BitLocker.

I remember turning on / off Secure Boot and PTT. And unfortunately I selected Clear PTT.
If I chose "Clear PTT" in UEFI, did I lose the encryption keys?
There is a way to decrypt the disk?

Comment: "Did I lose the encryption keys?" - If you cleared the fTPM (PTT on Intel systems) then you cleared the stored key. "There is a way to decrypt the disk?" - Yes; Use the BitLocker Recovery key when prompted when booting to the disk.

Comment: I don't have a recovery key :( I didn't even know I had encryption turned on.

Comment: If you don't have the BitLocker Recovery key and you didn't suspend BitLocker protection before you cleared the stored keys, you are out of luck trying to boot into Windows since the drive is encrypted. Since BitLocker is **never** enabled without user input, I suspect you actually had Device Encryption enabled, Device Encryption is enabled on certain classes of devices. Regardless if BitLocker or Device Encryption was enabled, the situation is the same, you will have to reinstall Windows.

Comment: I installed the system from the factory DELL image and apparently there is a different encryption key.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "a different key", the factory Dell image, is just a modified Windows image with Dell software.  BitLocker cannot be enabled out of the box without user intervention.

Comment: Clear PTT wipes the keys, but "Reset" does not (in case you might have swapped the two). Dell has a list of troubleshooting steps here https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-sr/000103639/how-to-troubleshoot-and-resolve-common-issues-with-tpm-and-bitlocker but you are probably out of luck

Comment: Dell does enable automatic bitlocker encryption on their images in newer versions of windows: "After a clean installation of Windows 11 or Windows 10 is completed and the out-of-box experience (OOBE) is finished, the computer is prepared for first use. As part of this preparation, BitLocker device encryption is initialized on the Operating System drive and fixed data drives." https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000124701/automatic-windows-device-encryption-bitlocker-on-dell-systems

Comment: @Cpt.Whale - I indicated it's not enabled without user intervention, the OBE can only be completed, with user intervention. Looking at the article, "Self-Encrypting Drives (SED) are automatically encrypted by Bitlocker in Windows 10 1709 and higher.", is likely the real reason the drive was encrypted. It's not even clear the user is running Windows 10 Professional.

Comment: Windows 10 Home and upgrade to Windows 11

Comment: Look at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/finding-your-bitlocker-recovery-key-in-windows-6b71ad27-0b89-ea08-f143-056f5ab347d6 for ways to retrieve that numerical password.

Comment: It does not work,
There was no Microsoft account or key export.